# Importing Office 365 liscense data into an Access database

Tags: ms-access, office365

I'm looking to tie in office 365 info into my Access database so that I know what licenses are assigned to each user. I've looked into using SharePoint but that appears to be a dead end. I'm sure there is some way to do it with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to automate that. You can manually create a table and name it Office 365, add the corresponding columns and track your licenses via sophisticated queries.

Comment: This is rather silly, how are companies supposed to track their licenses without paying some third party an exorbitant amount to do what Microsoft should already be doing?

Comment: You don't have to pay a third party. Go and view all your licenses in a list view in the admin section of office365. Then just copy and paste it to, OneNote, Excel, or Access, to keep track of it. It's quite simple.